# Problems with realloc, makes program crash

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

Hello i'implementing a smart vector in c, and i'm having problems with the reallocation of the buffer.

this is the struct that contains the array and its infos:

```
struct _vector
{
    item* vec;
    size_t elements;
    size_t size;
};
```

item is just a typedef that in this case happens to be int.
I made several function to manage the array, but the one that should resize it, gives me problems.

(Vector is also a typedef for struct _vector* by the way)

This is the function:

```
void insertVector(const Vector vec,const int pos,const item a)
{
    if(vec->elements==vec->size)
    {
        item* temp=realloc(vec->vec,(vec->size*2)*sizeof(item));
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            puts("Error: space unavailable");
            return;
        }
        //vec->vec=realloc(vec->vec,(vec->size*2)*sizeof(item));
        vec->vec=temp;
        vec->size*=2;
    }
    int size=vec->elements;
    if(pos>=0&&pos<=size)
    {
        for(int i=size;i>pos;i--)
        {
            vec->vec[i]=vec->vec[i-1];
        }
        vec->vec[pos]=a;
        vec->elements+=1;
        printf("size is %lu\nelements are %lu\n",vec->size,vec->elements);
    }
}
```

I just shift the contents to make space for the new element, and it works fine, the problem is when the array is reallocated.
when the number of valid elements is equal to the actual size of the array,
i do a realloc to double the actual size.
As soon as that if activates though the realloc makes the program crash with this error:incorrect checksum for freed object.

The problem is in the if, because it only crashes when the size and elements are equal, if i comment out that section, everything works
I don't know what could it be.

EDIT:
The functions that i used to create and the initialise the instance i'm working with are:

```
Vector newVector(void)
{
    Vector new=malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->vec=NULL;
    new->elements=0;
    new->size=0;
    return new;
}
```

and

```
void initVector(const Vector vec,const size_t size) 
{
    vec->vec=calloc(size,sizeof(item));
    vec->elements=size;
    vec->size=size*2;
}
```

Comment: If you comment out code and it magically works, that's usually a sign of UB

Comment: @yano If it is crashing it is definitely UB :) The OP is asking why... I guess [MCVE] is needed

Comment: your `for` loop starts at `i=size`,, I suspect `vec[size]` is out of bounds... but there could be UB in code not shown also.

Comment: @yano `vec[size]` would be in bounds after the `realloc`. @Adonai how did you initialize `vec` when you pass to `insertVector`?

Comment: if first init of `vec->vec` is a static array (not dynamically allocated) then the problem is explained.

Comment: @Pablo ah yes, you are correct

Comment: @Pablo I created a new vector setting to zero every field, then i used
this function: 
void initVector(const Vector vec,const size_t size) 
{
    vec->vec=calloc(size,sizeof(item));
    vec->elements=size;
    vec->size=size*2;
}

Comment: @Adonai please put that code in your question

Comment: So you are setting your `vec->size` to twice what you allocated in `initVector`

Comment: @Pablo done, mnistic size is not the number of elements, it is the size of the memory buffer, i made the function so that when the number of element are equal to the buffer the buffer doubles.

Comment: Yes but you are setting to twice what it should be

Comment: yeah in `initVector` seems like to me that should be `vec->elements = 0;` and `vec->size = size;`. If you're only allocating `size` space for `vec->vec` and then access `size*2`, you're out of bounds.

Comment: if you are on linux run your program under valgrind

Comment: @mnistic OMG you are right!!!!!! i just have to put size*2 inside calloc. Thanks!

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` ) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based of your comment

> I created a new vector setting to zero every field, then i used this function:
>
> ```
> void initVector(const Vector vec,const size_t size) 
> { 
>     vec->vec=calloc(size,sizeof(item));
>     vec->elements=size;
>     vec->size=size*2; 
> }
> ```

I think you are treating the size and the number of elements incorrectly. The
`initVector` function just allocates memory for the `vec->vec` array, so
`vec->elements` should be 0, not `size`. And `vec->size` should be `size`, not
`size*2`. So the correct function should be

```
// remove the const, you are modifying the data vec is pointing to
int initVector(Vector vec, size_t size)
{
    if(vec == NULL)
        return 0;

    vec->vec = calloc(size, sizeof *vec->vec);
    if(vec->vec == NULL)
        return 0;

    vec->elements = 0;
    vec->size = size;
    return 1;
}
```

Now the `insertVector` would only allocate new space, when all allocated spaces
are used.

And I suggest you use `memmove` to copy the memory:

```
// again, remove the const here
int insertVector(Vector vec, const size_t pos, const item a)
{
    if(vec == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(vec->elements==vec->size)
    {
        item* temp=realloc(vec->vec,(vec->size*2)*sizeof *temp);
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: space unavailable\n");
            return 0;
        }

        vec->vec=temp;
        vec->size*=2;
    }

    // I use vec->elements as upper limit,
    // otherwise you could have "holes" in the array and
    // you wouldn't realize it.
    if(pos < 0 || pos > vec->elements)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid position\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memmove(vec->vec + pos + 1, vec->vec + pos, (vec->elements - pos) * sizeof *vec->vec);

    vec->vec[pos] = a;
    vec->elements += 1;

    printf("size is %lu\nelements are %lu\n",vec->size,vec->elements);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: now that i think about it, i don't get why it works anyway with const...

Comment: @Adonai  I realized now, that's because of the `typedef`, the `const` applies to the pointer. If you did `vec = malloc(sizeof *vec)` then you would get this error: *error: assignment of read-only parameter `vec`*. If you would declare `insertVector` as `int insertVector(const struct  _vector *vec, ...)` then your would get an error telling you cannot change the contents.

Answer (score 0):

In your `initVector` function, you set the size incorrectly, to two times what you allocated with `calloc`. This memory then gets overwritten as you are adding new elements and this is the reason the `free` fails when you finally invoke `realloc`. Change `initVector` to:

```
void initVector(const Vector vec,const size_t size) 
{
    vec->vec=calloc(size,sizeof(item));
    vec->elements=size;
    vec->size=size;
}
```

Comment: yes i managed to see that, i put size*2 inside calloc, and now it works.

Comment: I still think that `vec->elements` should be initialized with 0, because you have only allocated space, not assign any `item`, so you have 0 elements.

Comment: it actually doesn't cause problems, because once the vector is initialised, i use elements as an upper bound for a for loop with which i fill the vector... but this is just for test purposes otherwise i should have put the element one by one.